# Javascript error on String (unterminated string literal)

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have got something like the following in my jsp:

```
var test = <%=Num%>;
```

and Num in this case is something like 12345678,john,smith.

But when I load the page I get the following error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

Can anyone help me out, thanks

Comment: Can you give some more strings from your code? It can be some quotes in `Num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not only number in your value, it's not a number so you need to treat it as a `String` and wrap your value in quotes

```
var test = "<%=Num%>";
```

Comment: Still get the error message 
Error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
Line: 2816, Column: 15
Source code:
    var test = "12345678,john,smith

Comment: It's telling you you must have matching quotes. Perhaps the last character in the string is a backslash (\) that is quoting the quote (")?

Comment: it could be \n as of line break! could you offer a solution if that the case?

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = '<%=Num%>';
```

Wrap it in quotes

Comment: Still get the error message 
Error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
Line: 2816, Column: 15
Source code:
    var test = "12345678,john,smith

Comment: Are you using single quotes?

Comment: My guess is that there might be quotes in the content?

Comment: No but I suspect there is a line break at the end of it. any idea on how to avoid a line break?!

Answer (score 0):

Try `var test = "<%=Num%>";`

Comment: Still get the error message 
Error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
Line: 2816, Column: 15
Source code:
    var test = "12345678,john,smith

Answer (score 0):

Please [avoid](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2010/07/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files.html) using `scriplets`

```
 var test = "${Num}";
```